# External USB Drive Detached - what is causing it? // uas_eh_abort_handler

Tags: 22.04, external-hdd

I have an external HDD (Seagate RSS LLC Backup Plus Slim) on which a program as heavily writing tonight.

When I checked this morning, I could see that the "lsblk" does not show the harddrive anymore, and I could also not mount it with "sudo mount -a".

The "dmesg" suggest that something happened at around 03:32, logs below:
https://pastebin.com/raw/BXNMupVr

I am trying to decipher the messages, and feel here is where things start to go south:

> [Thu Aug 10 03:32:37 2023] sd 0:0:0:0:
> [sda] tag#11 uas_eh_abort_handler 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD OUT

Which eventually looks to me like it shut down the USB ports:

> [Thu Aug 10 03:33:38 2023] usb 1-1:
> USB disconnect, device number 2

> [Thu Aug 10 03:33:38 2023] usb 2-2:
> USB disconnect, device number 2

Where I am bumping my head against the wall is to figure out what has happened exactly / what caused it, so that I can figure out how to prevent it in the future.

As said, I know the HDD was under heavy write-operations at the time. But heavy write alone should not trigger the above, thus trying to understand how to prevent such situation going forward.

My hunch from looking into this so far is that it has to to with "UAS" as opposed to "USB-Storage", but I am not sure I fully have understood it. ([Potentially related issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239782/connection-problem-with-usb3-external-storage-on-linux-uas-driver-problem)). Also looking into this [UAS deactivation tutorial](https://leo.leung.xyz/wiki/How_to_disable_USB_Attached_Storage_(UAS)).

Thank you all for any pointers

**Update and potential solution**

It seems that the UAS driver can cause issues, and changing to the USB-Storage driver may help.

1. Check if the HDD is on UAS by using "lsusb" and comparing the Bus/Device to "lsusb -t"
   [How to check if UAS](https://dannyda.com/2022/05/18/how-to-check-if-the-usb-device-supports-is-using-usb-attached-scsi-uas-or-usb-attached-scsi-protocol-uasp-from-windows-windows-server-linux-debian-ubuntu-kali-linux-fedora-redhat-rocky-linux-etc/)
2. Change the driver from UAS to USB-Storage
   [How to change UAS to USB-Storage](https://leo.leung.xyz/wiki/How_to_disable_USB_Attached_Storage_(UAS))

Answer (score 0):

> Update and potential solution
>
> It seems that the UAS driver can cause issues, and changing to the
> USB-Storage driver may help.
>
> ```
> Check if the HDD is on UAS by using "lsusb" and comparing the Bus/Device to "lsusb -t" How to check if UAS
>
> Change the driver from UAS to USB-Storage How to change UAS to USB-Storage
> ```

This has saved me after days of trying to get a LaCie Rugged USB3 disk working on my machine.  Much appreciated!